# Starting new Activity from helper class

Tags: android-activity, start-activity, startactivityforresult

I have a class called `PhotoManager` which deals with getting the proper permissions, accessing the camera or gallery and returns a `Bitmap`. This class gets called from other classes that need to update a users profile picture etc. like so

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //user wants to take a picture
                    profilePic.setImageBitmap(photoManager.userWantsToTakePicture());
                }
```

I call `startActivityForResult()` in PhotoManager but it isn't working. Here's my function

```
public Bitmap userWantsToUploadPicture(){

    int permissionChecker = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if(permissionChecker == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        //THIS NEXT LINE DOES NOT WORK
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), SELECT_FILE);
        return selectedImage;
    }
    else{
        --do stuff
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread 
android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object 
reference
```

and I'm not sure why my intent is null seeing as I have initialized it.

Also, I ran this code in the class that updates user's profile picture, and it ran fine. It is only an issue when I run the code from the PhotoManager class

`PhotoManager()` has a constructor

```
public PhotoManager(Context c, Activity a){
    context = c;
    activity = a;
}
```

Comment: What is `context` in this case? Where it that coming from?

Comment: sorry, context is `classname.this` that I pass in from the the class calling `photoManager` if that make sense - I just edited my Q

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer to your question, but you've got some issues that are probably causes and fixing those might help you find a solution:

First, I would advise against passing `Context`s and `Activity`s around as arguments to classes. If you need one, pass it in to the calling method when you need it and use the most local `Context` you have available.

```
public Bitmap userWantsToUploadPicture(Context context) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

If you hold on to those references you will leak memory and can be using a stale object that was otherwise rendered useless (an `Activity` that has called `finish()` for example.

Second, an `Activity` *is* a `Context`, so having a constructor that takes both is redundant.

Third, your method supposedly returns a `Bitmap`, but it's starting another `Activity` to pick the photo, so there's no way you'll have a `Bitmap` to return.